# What's the ClrLn command in Xcode?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode

I **somehow** ended up with a ClrLn command in my Xcode text key bindings, the Delete command.

What is the ClrLn command and how did I get it to appear there? What keystroke combination on the keyboard results in a ClrLn command being issued?

Answer (score 2):

My new flat, wired, full-sized, aluminum-looking keyboard seems to emit a ClrLn when I press the button marked with the word "clear" in the keypad area. It looks like this:

[image: Trying to be clear :)]

Still not sure what this/"the Delete action" is supposed to do in Xcode though.

Comment: which button is "clear" button?

Comment: On US English keyboards, it has the word "clear" on the key. Cf. updated answer with image above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are describing. What does “ClrLn” mean? Which delete key are you talking about?

In my Xcode 2.5, the ⌦ key (forward delete; on full keyboards, the one in the 2x3 keypad between the main set of keys and the numeric keypad) is bound to the Action **Delete Forward** (along with <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, shown as ^D).

If you have somehow assigned the key forward delete to something else, just reassign it to **Delete Forward** and it will be removed from whatever action it is currently assigned. If you want to preserve the ^D binding, click the plus button that is displayed after double-clicking in the actions's  **Keys** column. To exit key-assignment mode, just click on another line the **Action**/**Keys** table.

If you are talking about the other delete key (⌫; backwards delete; the one immediately to the right of <kbd>=</kbd> on most US keyboards), then that is usually bound to **Indent Friendly Delete Backward** (in Xcode 2.5).

There are several actions that might be your “ClrLn”: **Delete to Beginning of Line**, **Delete to Beginning of Paragraph**, **Delete to End of Line**, **Delete to End of Paragraph**. In these *line* means to the next/previous “soft” line break (wrap due to window width), *paragraph* means to the next/previous “hard” line break (CR/CRLF/LF sequence in the file). None of these are assigned a key in the default Xcode 2.5 configuration.

Comment: ClrLn is the keystroke, Delete is the action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what key stroke combination you used, but you might want to try the Xcode shortcuts located *[Complete Xcode Keyboard Shortcut List](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/02/complete-xcode-keyboard-shortcut-list.html)*.

You might be able to reproduce.

Comment: ClrLn is on that list: for action Delete, press ClrLn

Comment: @Peter Please take more care when editing others' posts. The first sentence's grammar seems broken.